# Device rotation Portrait/Landscape viewport

Tags: html, css, ios, viewport

i have a problem width the viewport of an iPhone 8 plus. The Code below is working width an ipad Air 3 (2019). If i rotate the iPhone 8 plus or a iPhone XS Max in Landscape and than back in Porttrait, the browser safari and firefox adds a additional space in portrait screen. But not in the Landscape screen. But it becomes more special: It shows only this behavior if no additional tap is opend and not in every casse. Do you have an idea why it behaves that way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titel</title>
    <style>
        * {
            
            padding: 0;
            margin:0;
        } 
      
     </style>
  </head>
  <body style="height:100%; background-color:grey;display:grid;grid-template-rows:120px 60px calc(100% - 180px)">
      <div style="background-color:green;height:100%;"></div>
      <div style="background-color:red;height:100%;"></div>
      <div style="background-color:blue;height:100%;"></div>
  </body>
 <script>
    
      let winGroesse = window.innerHeight;
      let winGroesseout;
          
      window.onresize = reSizeFunkt;
      
      let neueWinGroesse = winGroesse.toString() + "px";
      
      document.querySelector('html').style.height = neueWinGroesse; 
        
      function reSizeFunkt () {
          
          winGroesse = window.innerHeight;
          
          neueWinGroesse = winGroesse.toString() + "px";
         
          document.querySelector('html').style.height = neueWinGroesse; 
           
          
      }
    
    
</script>   
    
</html>
```

[bevor rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/622sw.jpg)
[after rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHhWv.png)

Answer (score 0):

i've still not found a solution. But should someone else have that trouble i share here my ugly workaround:

```
      let winGroesse = window.innerHeight;
      let winGroesseout;
          
      window.onresize = reSizeFunkt;
      
      let neueWinGroesse = winGroesse.toString() + "px";
      
      document.querySelector('html').style.height = neueWinGroesse; 
        
      function reSizeFunkt () {
          
          winGroesse = window.innerHeight;
          
          neueWinGroesse = winGroesse.toString() + "px";

          document.querySelector('html').style.height = neueWinGroesse; 
         
        **setTimeout(function() {
            winGroesse = window.innerHeight;
            neueWinGroesse = winGroesse.toString() + "px";
            document.querySelector('html').style.height = neueWinGroesse;
        }, 300);**
     

      };
```

I figured out, that the rezise needs an moment so I set a 2nd function width a delay of 300ms. It does what it's supposed to do but I think there is a clean way

still hoping there is a real solution